# A continuous map from the unit circle $S_1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $S_1$ be the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then there is a continuous one-one onto function from $S_1\setminus\{(0,1)\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, which I can show by shifting the circle along the positive direction of the $y$-axis by one unit, so that it has the center $(0,1)$, and then get the image of any point on the circumference (except the topmost point $(0,2)$), as the point of intersection of the straight line passing through $(0,2)$ and the given point, with the $x$-axis.

Now I want to know **if $f:S_1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is any continuous function, then are there countably or uncountably many points $x,y\in S_1$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$**?

Comment: If you take constant function, you get uncountable such points, but you can also map Unit circle to non negative reals with no two points mapped to same value.

Comment: @jnyan can you elaborate the second mapping from Unit circle to non negative reals

Comment: Every point on unit circle is mapped to $[0,2pi)$. From there try $x/(1-{x/2pi})$

Comment: Thanks a lot. But there can be no one one and onto continuous function from $S_1$ tp $\mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: Correct. You can Remove a point from unit circle, and remaining thing is still connected. But if you do so on reals you get a disconnected set. Continuous functions map connected sets to connected sets

Comment: @jnyan That function is not continuous.

Comment: Why not, it is a rational function and denominator is continuous on [0,2pi)

Comment: The map from $S^1$ to $[0,2\pi)$ is not continuous, at the point that maps to $0$.

Comment: Thank you. Unit circle being compact and all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if $f: S^1\to\mathbb R$ is continuous, then **there are uncountably many** pairs of points $x\neq y\in S^1$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$.

Proof: If $f$ is a constant function, then we're done. Otherwise there are $a,b\in S^1$ such that $f(a)<f(b)$. Let $c$ be any number in the interval $(f(a), f(b))$. Then there exists an $x$ on the clockwise arc from $a$ to $b$, and a $y$ on the counterclockwise arc from $a$ to $b$, such that $f(x)=f(y)=c$. Now note that there are uncountably many choices for $c$.

(This works because both arcs in $S^1$ are connected. By contrast, in $S_1\setminus\{(0,1)\}$, one of the arcs is not connected. That is why you were able to find a one-to-one map.)

By the way, to answer your question in the comments: $f: S^1\to\mathbb R$ cannot be onto, because the image of a compact space under a continuous function is compact.

(This works because $S^1$ is compact. By contrast, $S_1\setminus\{(0,1)\}$ isn't compact. That is why you were able to find an onto map.)

Comment: A variation on this theme: For convenience, identify $S^1$ with $\{z\in \Bbb C: |z|=1\}. $ For non-constant $f$ let $f(a)=\min f(S^1)$ and $b=\max f(S^1)$ with $a\ne b$... (...$ a$ and  $b$   exist because $S^1$ is compact.) .  There exist real $u,v$ with $a=\exp (iu)$ and $b=\exp (iv)$ with $u<v<u+2\pi.$ Then $f$ maps both of the disjoint sets $\{\exp (ix): u<x<v\}, \; \{\exp (ix): v<x<u+2\pi\}$ onto  sets that cover the real interval $(f(a),f(b)).$.................+1